# Smoke Hit Adaptive domain + Humidifier Smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

I struggle with smoke in blender. I try to do a smoke for an humidifier product (photo ref), but I tried a lot of settings and I don't know how I can achieve this result.

[image]

Everytime I simulate smoke with Adaptative domain or not, the smoke hit the adaptive domain, and I wanted more to have like a "continue smoke".

[image]

Have you got tips or any tuts to advice, it will be very nice!

Thank you :)

Comment: The smoke does not hit the _Adaptive Domain_, the _Adaptive Domain_ expands as much as it needs to contain the generated smoke (it _adapts_ to the smoke). Are you sure your smoke is not simply reaching the boundary of the original smoke domain overall? The _Adaptive Domain_ becomes smaller than the original domain if the smoke does not fill it completely (to avoid simulating what is considered empty space according to the set density threshold), but it cannot extend the original domain. I guess your "with Adaptive domain or not" hints on that your domain is simply too small.

Comment: To make it more clear since it seems there is a misunderstanding of the smoke simulation on your side or a misunderstandable phrasing in the question: If you mean the smoke should go further than the domain boundary, well this is simply not possible since the domain defines the space in which smoke will be simulated. If you just phrased it misunderstandably and you mean, you don't want it to look as if it stops at the boundary but seems to flow "out" of the domain, check the _Border Collisions_. In your second screenshot it looks like _Bottom_ is enabled, so the lower border acts as a floor.